# Android: Do I have to send all the variables to retain the values before fragment transaction?

Tags: android, android-fragments

Suppose I have 2 fragments A and B. A has 2 integer variables named data_1=2 and data_2=3. I do a transaction from **Fragment A -> Fragment B**. Note that Fragment B needs only data_1 but it doesn't need data_2, so, I send only the variable **data_1** through Bundle. So, when I do another transaction from **Fragment B -> Fragment A**, sending back the modified value of data_1, I will use the new value of data_1 but will the original value of **data_2 = 3** be retained ?

If not, then how do I retain this value?

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted your code.

Comment: You can make it so that you hold the data in the Activity and implement an interface so your child fragments can access the data they need without having to pass data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are various ways of doing it, but the easiest way in my Opinion would be to share data with the parent activity.

Basically like so:

```
class MainActivity extends Activity {
     public static int data_1 = 1, data_2 = 2;


     //All your other code goes here
}
```

Then in your child fragment to set the data you would go:

```
MainActivity.data_1 = 5;
```

Whereas to read the data you just call the static value.

```
int current_data = MainActivity.data_1;
```

If you need instances of the activity for whatever reason you can set up getter and setter functions for an instance's
(not static) variable.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Sometimes I get real confused with the stuff and forget the basics of Java.

Comment: Yeah there are a lot of patterns you can use in these cases to share the data.  But don't forget the basics :)

Answer (score 0):

you can also use onSavedInstanceState(Bundle outstate) callback method of fragment and set your value in the bundle. So when you come back to previous fragment, you will get the retain value from the bundle of the onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) callback method.